# How to check if a coordinate is adjacent to another?

Tags: java, game-development

I am writing a snake game. I want to write a method to check if the head (index 0) is next to any other body part. I am not sure what is going wrong, but this method does not do anything. I have it set so that if it returns true the game ends (for testing purposes)
Here is my code:

```
public boolean headNextToBody()
{
    boolean xClose = false;
    boolean yClose = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++)
    {
        if( x[i] == (x[0] + 1) || x[i] == (x[0] - 1))
        {
            xClose = true;
        }
        if(y[i] == y[0] + 1 || y[i] == y[0] - 1)
        {
            yClose = true;
        }
    }
    return (xClose && yClose);
}
```

Comment: What does "does not do anything" mean? It should just return a value. Does it return a wrong one?

Comment: Sorry, I should have spoken more clearly. Im assuming it always returns false, and Im not sure why

Comment: Ok, you should give a bit more context. For example this will surely return false if `bodyParts` is 0, so it would help to know what value it has, what are `x` and `y` etc. In any case, you should use a debugger (or even just use `System.out.println`) to see where the code goes and what values those variables assume.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, no need to include the head (at position 0) in the test, as it will always be false.

```
for(int i = 1; i < bodyParts; i++)
```

The conditions for adjacency are

```
(y[i] == y[0]) && (x[i] == (x[0] + 1) || x[i] == (x[0] - 1))
```

or

```
(x[i] == x[0]) && (y[i] == (y[0] + 1) || y[i] == (y[0] - 1))
```

If either of these are true for any non-head point on the snake you can return `true` immediately, otherwise return `false`.

You can combine the separate tests into a single `if` statement:

```
public boolean headNextToBody()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < bodyParts; i++)
    {
        if(((y[i] == y[0]) && (x[i] == (x[0] + 1) || x[i] == (x[0] - 1))) ||
           ((x[i] == x[0]) && (y[i] == (y[0] + 1) || y[i] == (y[0] - 1)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively you could shorten the test a little by using some math:

```
public boolean headNextToBody()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < bodyParts; i++)
    {
        if(1 == ((x[i]-x[0])*(x[i]-x[0]) + (y[i]-y[0])*(y[i]-y[0]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also no need to include the second segment of the snake as it is always adjacent to the head